# Problems with ActionBarSherlock and Android Studio

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to use the ActionBarSherlock in Android Studio but i have a problem.
They told me to add this to build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
}
```

but when i start the application i get this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':Ugho:processDefaultFlavorDebugResources'.
```

> Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':Ugho:processDefaultFlavorDebugResources'

If i try to write "gradlew clean" in the terminal i get "BUILD SUCCESSFUL".

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: What if you do ./gradlew clean assembleDebug to try to build it at the command line? Same issue?

Comment: Yes, i get the same error :(

Comment: can you run it with --debug and post the stacktrace?

Comment: How can i copy and paste here the output of the terminal? It's very long..

Answer (score 0):

Executing tasks: [:UGHO:assembleDebug]

:UGHO:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:UGHO:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:UGHO:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:UGHO:prepareComActionbarsherlockActionbarsherlock440Library UP-TO-DATE
:UGHO:prepareDebugDependencies
:UGHO:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:UGHO:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:UGHO:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:UGHO:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:UGHO:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:UGHO:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:UGHO:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':UGHO:processDebugResources'.

> Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':UGHO:processDebugResources'